# Translate old german certificate

Tags: handwriting, blackletter

I have a birth certificate of Isaac [Epstein] but I can't translate it and understand what is written there. Can you help me? [image]

Comment: Welcome to german.SE! The question is likely to be considered off-topic on this site and to be closed. But it is a much better fit for [genealogy.SE](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com) and I encourage you to post it there (with tags "german" and "palaeography"). The users there have the specific kind of expertise needed.

Comment: @marquinho; I modified the tags but don't agree concerning closing and have some doubt in respect to genealogy. We have a number of comparable questions here. It would not hurt, if left and right margins were a bit further outside, or possible locations.

Comment: @marquinho I agree with guidot. Also see the relevant post on meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked the related handwritten alphabet?

Comment: @guidot and Kirill, I'm sorry. I actually intended to *warn* OP that some close votes were coming (as has happened in the past and did happen this time), but my wording was not ideal – it might have come across as a rejection. Sorry about that. (Personally, I'm in favor of transcription requests!) As for genealogy.SE, they get frequent requests of this kind (the tags [palaeography] and [birth-records] are both in the 200s) and they are usually good at illuminate the context (provenance, place names), so I do think that'd be a good place to ask. But our own community did a good job here! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ester geb Epstein ledig
> in [Ipcźien], Tochter des Simon
> und der [Feigel] Epstein
> gewesene Schänker in
> [Bratocice]

I'm not sure about some of the names and place names, hence they are in square brackets. Bratocice might be [Bratucice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratucice), maybe?
"geb" is short for "geborene" (née).
"Schänker" probably refers to the parents job, running a bar/tavern.

Comment: [This page](https://www.geni.com/people/Zipora-Feigel-Epstein/6000000006175177792) suggests, that *Feigel* (instead of *Teigel*) is valid first name, translating to *Zipora*.

Comment: Thank you but can you write meaning of all of this in English, please?

Comment: If *ledig* (English: *single*) is correct, this raises some doubts, whether the document from the question can be a birth certificate of *Esther* and why it is necessary to state her birth name.

Comment: @guidot: To take your reflections further: All of this would make sense if the snippet were from a *marriage* register. Prior to this marriage, she is "ledig" (as opposed to, say, "verwitwet") and the (soon to be changed) birth name is stated.

Comment: This is Isaak's borth certificate and this is information about his mother and her parents

Comment: Bratocice also exists. See https://books.google.de/books?id=dqI4l8M-drcC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=Bratocice&source=bl&ots=PxmaCIMj0l&sig=ACfU3U3wwuEwtmu0o1U0AuFT7VZZrK_7jg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWtLDggdD1AhWAiv0HHfFVAxoQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=Bratocice&f=false

Comment: @КириллКенигсберг I'm sorry, but this community had decided that we don't offer translation, otherwise we would be flooded by requests. Hence, I only transcribed the old handwriting and translated the abbreviations and words, a machine translation might miss. I recommend deepl.com - they do quite good German > English.

Answer (score 1):

I compile all facts from answer and comments plus some corrections into a community wiki.

Ester geb Epstein XXXX [Ester née Epstein XXXX]
in Jaśien, Tochter des Simon [in Jaśien, daughter of Simon]
und der Feigel Epstein [and Feigel Epstein]
gewesene Schänker in [defunct inn-keepers in]
Bratocice.

I can't decipher the word after "Epstein" in line 1, but I doubt that it is "ledig" [unmarried] which would contradict the fact **née Epstein**. Perhaps the first character is not a letter but a "/". As regards contents, it could stand for "born" or "resident".

Comment: In context, "ledig" makes perfect sense. OP said the snippet is part 2 of [this birth certificate](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69489/). There, the father was given as "E. S. Epstein, **ledig**, Schenker in Jaśien": largely the same format as Ester's info. The child was born *out of wedlock*, which checks with the parents being *ledig*. True, if Ester is unmarried, *strictly speaking* her maiden name is not needed. I assume the clerk 1. made a slip of the pen, *out of habit*, or 2. *chose* to state that Epstein is her *own* name, regardless of the husband's name (also "Epstein").

Comment: @marquinho You should include your interpretation into the community wiki. If I understand correctly you suspect that Isaak was the son of "Efraim Samuel Epstein not-married innkeeper in Jaśien" and Ester Epstein (the geb = née being a mistake of the registrar) not-married in Jaśien. Okay, probably the name "Epstein" had a high occurence, thus it may have been a pure coincidence that both unmarried parents had the same family name. Or they could have been relatives (e.g. cousins or something more distant) which could suggest that Ester's parents

Comment: (who have been inn-keepers) transferred their inn to Efraim (perhaps a nephew) while Ester worked in the inn. Pure speculation ...