# Old german certificate

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

Can you translate what is written here, please? [image]

Comment: Which part(s) of the certificate do you wish for? Print or handwriting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Related to https://german.stackexchange.com/q/69482/34192.

Comment: Why was this question closed? The reason given is "This question asks for translating or proofreading a text." But this does not apply. The linked meta post says *As the title of this question says, are questions like “I wrote this text in German language … Is it grammatically correct?” on topic for this site?* Moreover, deciphering requests are not off-topic in this forum. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form is bilingual, in German and Polish. I only translate the German parts, I guess the Polish parts of the form will be the same. I try to decipher the handwriting, and indicate where I am not sure.

- [day missing]
- "Jänner" (austrian for "January")
- "1885"
- "Jaśien" [This could refer to  one of the [several places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasie%C5%84) currently named Jaśien, some of which are in the formerly Austrian part of southern Poland]. The letter "ś" is Polish; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A).
- "60"

and these lines are repeated:

- "23"
- "Jänner"
- "1885"
- "Jaśien"
- "60" (this is the street/house number: the correspondent column header reads [Hau]"s-Nr." / "Nr. domu")

The column entries read:

- Name des Kindes [name of the child]: Isaak
- Geschlecht [sex]: männlich [male]
- Eheliche, angeblich eheliche oder uneheliche Geburt [Legitmate, allegedly legitimate or illegitimate birth]: unehelich [illegitimate, i.e. the parents have not been married]
- Vor- und Zuname des Vaters, sowie Stand, Beschäftigung und Wohnort [first and last name of the father, marital status, profession and residence]: Efraim Samuel Epstein ledig Schenker in Jaśien [Efraim Samuel Epstein not-married innkeeper in Jaśien]

The titles of the first two large columns (no. 2-3) are largely missing, but it's safe to assume that the first one records the birth date and the second one the date of inscription in the birth registry. (Entries in a birth register are also assigned a sequence number, or another unique identifier. This will have been in the narrow column no. 1, which is completely illegible due to damage.)

The birth certificate was certainly issued in [Galicia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galicia_(Eastern_Europe)). This is indicated by the fact that the doucument is bilingual (German / Polish) and the word "Jänner" is typical Austrian; therefore it can be concluded that it was used in the part of Austria-Hungary with a substantial Polish population share. The place "Jaśien" is probably located in one of the regions [Kałusz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezirk_Ka%C5%82usz) or [Brzesko](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezirk_Brzesko).

*Remark:*

The profession "Schenker" can mean "Schankwirt" [inn-keeper] or "Schankkellner" [barman / waiter]. See [here](http://www.lessner-ahnenforschung.com/7c3b98951054da99149c17dcbb279db8_Alte%20Berufsbezeichnungen.pdf).

Comment: This is government document